# Convert a DataFrame of 2 columns into a dict ColA -> ColB

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

If I had a DataFrame of 2 columns(a and b)
How do I convert this into a dictionary mapping a->b?
(None of the DataFrame.to_dict() options is doing what I want

```
pd.DataFrame(data={ 'a':[1,3], 'b':[2,4]})
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

and I want a resulting dictionary like

```
{ 1:2, 3:4 }
```

This works but there must be a better way?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'a':[1,3], 'b':[2,4]})
>>> { r[1][0] : r[1][1] for r in df.iterrows() }
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.set_index('a')['b'].to_dict()
```

Or

```
dict(zip(df['a'], df['b']))

#output
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Comment: Cool, I know it had to be easy.. but now I have to benchmark those 2 solutions.  Thanks!

Comment: { r[0] : r[1] for i,r in df.iterrows() } ... this works, but is 125 times slower.  The set_index solution is about 8% faster than the dict+zip.  I would guess building the python dictionary dominates the time and compiled pandas is about the same speed as compiled Python dict+zip code.  ... set_index is faster, but I have to say the dict+zip solution seems simple and maybe more flexible (and not much slower).

Answer (score 1):

```
df.set_index('a').to_dict()['b']
```

gives:

```
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```